# Displaying Item when i clicked it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I just make selectable in jQuery the selectable and click functions done but I need a help or any codes hint to know just how to display item that I clicked on it beside the selectable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you actually get a meaningful answer, I recommend you check out [this post on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// hide element

```
$("#hideElement").click(function(){
    $("h2").hide();
});
```

// show element

```
$("#showElement").click(function(){
    $("h2").show();
});
```

Comment: hello thank you but h2 reference for what ?

Comment: for example->      <h2>click me!</h2>